# Apache Redirect - same domain different REQUEST_URI

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need multiple RewriteCond for the same domain, but different REQUEST_URIs
I need to redirect to a different domain depending on the REQUEST_URI.

I am trying this with no luck:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myuir/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myuniqueuri/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example2.com/$! [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myotheruniqueuri/ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example3.com/$! [R=301,L]
```

I thought the [OR] on the request uri condition would work, but it did not. I have also tried without the [OR] and it did not work!

For example:

if the url is:

```
http://example.com/myuniqueuri
```

needs to redirect to:

```
http://example2.com
```

if the url is:

```
http://example.com/myotheruniqueuri
```

needs to redirect to:

```
http://example3.com
```

where example2 and example3 can be anything but are not the same.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain exactly how you expect each of the redirects you are having problem with to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be in your syntax. The reference is $1 not $!. Also the `!` is being used incorrectly. This basically means `not`. Like if not this directory then etc. Well it appears you want to match the directory and then redirect based on that. Try this code and see if it works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myuir
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myuniqueuri
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example2.com/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myotheruniqueuri
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example3.com/ [R=301,L]
```